# Reading a file using fstream

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream

When I try to read a file to a buffer, it always appends random characters to the end of the buffer.

```
char* thefile;
    std::streampos size;

    std::fstream file(_file, std::ios::in | std::ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        size = file.tellg();
        std::cout << "size: " << size;
        thefile = new char[size]{0};

        file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
        file.read(thefile, size);
        std::cout << thefile;
    }

    int x = 0;
```

While my original text in my file is: "hello"
The output becomes: "helloýýýý««««««««þîþîþ"

Could anyone help me as to what is happening here? Thanks

Comment: What's the return value of the read function?

Comment: @DanielJour `stream.read(...) ` returns the stream itself.

Comment: Indeed, I was mistakenly thinking it would return the `gcount()`value, which is what actually should be checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is not opened with `ios::binary` mode, you cannot assume that the position returned by `tellg()`  will give you the number of chars that you will read. Text mode operation may perform some transformations on the flow (f.ex: on windows, it will convert "\r\n" in the file in "\n", so you might find out a size of 2 but read only 1)

Anyway, `read()` doesn't add a null terminator.

Finally,  you must allocate one more character than the size that you expect due to the null terminator that you have to add.  Otherwise you risk a buffer overflow when you add it.

You should verify how many chars were really [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read/) with [`gcount()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/gcount/), and set a null terminator to your string accordingly.

```
   thefile = new char[size + 1]{0};  // one more for the trailing null  
   file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
   if (file.read(thefile, size))
      thefile[size]=0;               // successfull read:  all size chars were read
   else thefile[file.gcount()]=0;   // or less chars were read due to text mode
```

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ docs: http://cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/read

"This function simply copies a block of data, without checking its contents nor appending a *null character* at the end."

So your string misses the trailing null character which indicates the end of the string. In this case `cout` will just continue printing characters from what is beyond `thefile` in memory.

Add a `'\0'` at the end of your string.

Comment: Expand your answer to contain the corrected code and it's perfect.

Comment: Thanks for this, I found it to be the clearest answer. What I did was simply add 1 to the size of the buffer and then made the last index = '\0'. Is there a better way or is this fine?

Comment: @DanielJour: I leave this up to the reader, I think it's clear how to do it.

Comment: ...and consider that there might be less chars read than expected (at least on platforms were text mode  is not identical to binary).

Comment: @Christophe: Of course this might be an issue but certainly not the reason for the misbehaviour presented in the question. I limited myself to answering the question. There are enough tutorials out there on how to do such things the right way.

Comment: @Matt setting the last index to zero is good habit, but you already initialise the whole array to zero, which is why you don't have to fear that read reads less characters than size either.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a better way of reading your collection:

```
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>

template<class T>
void Write(std::string const & path, T const & value, std::ios_base::openmode mode)
{               
    if (auto stream = std::ofstream(path, mode))
    {
        Write(stream, value);

        stream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create/open stream");
    }       
}

template<class T>
void Write(std::ostream & stream, T const & value)
{
    std::copy(value.begin(), value.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(stream));

    if (!stream)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to write");
    }
}

template<class T>
void Read(std::istream & stream, T & output)
{
    auto eof = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>();

    output = T(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(stream), eof);

    if(!stream)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to read stream");
    }
}

template<class T>
void Read(std::string const & path, T & output)
{               
    if (auto stream = std::ifstream(path, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary))
    {
        Read(stream, output);

        stream.close();
    }
    else
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("failed to create stream");
    }           
}


int main(void)
{
    // Write and read back text.

    {
        auto const s = std::string("I'm going to write this string to a file");

        Write("temp.txt", s, std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out);

        auto t = std::string();

        Read("temp.txt", t);
    }

    // Write and read back a set of ints.

    {
        auto const v1 = std::vector<int>() = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };

        Write("temp.txt", v1, std::ios_base::trunc | std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);

        auto v2 = std::vector<int>();

        Read("temp.txt", v2);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pass in an iterable container rather than using "new".